# Is it better to destroy all objects or just let the garbage collector do the job?

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a function like the following:

```
Public Function testFunction(ByVal input_string As String) As String

    Dim s As New StringBuilder()
    Dim c As Char
    For i As Integer = 0 To input_string.Length - 1
        c = input_string.Chars(i)
        s.Append(c)
    Next
    Return s.ToString

End Function
```

but I want know if it's better to explicitly destroy any object, like this:

```
    Public Function testFunction(ByVal input_string As String) As String

    Dim s As New StringBuilder()
    Dim c As Char
    For i As Integer = 0 To input_string.Length - 1
        c = input_string.Chars(i)
        s.Append(c)
    Next

    Dim t As String = s.ToString
    s = Nothing

    Return t

End Function
```

or just let the garbage collector do the job for us?

Both the above functions work, but I want only know the best practice for performance...

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's *always* better to let the garbage collector do the job for you.** Think about it like this: a programmer much smarter than you (and I) carefully optimized the garbage collection routine to make life much simpler and painless for you. It's unlikely that we can do a better job ourselves, and more likely that we'll just interfere.

Basically, objects that are instantiated as local variables will become eligible for garbage collection as soon as they fall out of scope (i.e., that method finishes execution). Your `StringBuilder` object is going to be garbage collected whenever the garbage collector runs (which is another thing you don't have to worry about—there is no way to know the next time the GC will run).

Setting an object to `Nothing` literally does nothing (note that this is different than pre-.NET versions of Visual Basic). It will generally be optimized out by the compiler in Release mode, and even if it isn't, it's not helping you in the least.

However, if an object has a [**`Dispose`** method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx), you should be calling it. Or better yet, wrap it in a [`Using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). But there's still no reason to set its reference to `Nothing`.

Comment: No, assigning a value to the reference does *not* count as accessing it, so the garbage collector will not refrain from collecting the object before that.

Comment: Thank You all, however I voted this bc it's the only one that mentions the dispose method.

Comment: @Max: `Dispose` and GC are orthogonal. `Dispose` is ideally for managing resources that the GC can't handle. So, `Dispose` isn't really germane to this question.

Comment: @Cody Gray: It's still not correct. The blog posting that you have read is not correct on this point. The garbage collector doesn't care *at all* about the null assignment (neither in debug or release mode), so it doesn't matter if it's optimised away or not. It's only the usage of the object that matters, and assigning a new value to the reference doesn't count as using the previous value.

Comment: @Jason: I meant just more accurate

Comment: @Guffa: Interesting. I've come across lots of evidence to the contrary, though I personally have not done any investigation or profiling. So I'm not disagreeing, but I'm curious if you have any reference confirming this. I suppose I'll leave the answer as is and let the comment exchange speak for itself.

Comment: @Max: An answer that contains extraneous details is not more accurate.

Comment: @Jason: Usually I prefer the details and implementation notes. Not only 4 lines.

Comment: @Max: Fine, next time you ask a question I'll make sure to include details about the history of World War II, the Byzantine Empire, and the theory of relativity. You seem to be missing the point that `Dispose` is not germane to your question.

Comment: @Jason: you are too comic; i'm not. It's not the World War/etc. I think it's useful for others make a simple note for the dispose method.

Comment: @Cody Gray: If you have found so much information suggesting the contrary, you should try it for yourself. It's easy using a WeakReference and GC.Collect to show that an object can be collected before the reference is assigned null.

Comment: @Guffa: I just tested this (though by implementing a finalizer in my own class instead of using a `WeakReference`) and confirmed to myself what you've been saying. I didn't have a chance to test it when I first posted, but I'm glad that I did. Perhaps this was the case with very early versions of the compiler (although it works as you describe as far back as v2.0), or people have just been passing around misinformation for quite a while on the Internet (gasp!). Either way, I'll update my post. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 6):

Setting `s = Nothing` is pointless as it falls out of scope at the very next instruction thus becoming eligible for garbage collection at that point anyway.

Setting a variable to null/nothing doesn't mean the garbage collection kicks in at that point.

Comment: @Mark - ok, bad terminology. I'll remove it.

Comment: Actually, it's usage that matters, not scope. The object falls out of use before the statement that sets the reference to Nothing.

Comment: @Marc - don't apologise. The whole point of SO is to provide accurate and (hopefully) complete answers so pick away.

Answer (score 1):

If an object doesn't implement `IDisposable` then you are correct to do nothing (you couldn't free the object if you wanted to).

If an object implements `IDisposble` you *must* call `.Dispose()` - you are using it wrong if you don't. The object can try to protect you from yourself, and call `Dispose` itself when it is being finalized (destroyed, freed), but objects are not *required* to do your work for you.

### See also

- [Proper use if IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface/538238#538238)

Answer (score 0):

Let the garbage collector do this.  Classes that implement the IDisposable interface are designed for you to manage pre-garbage collector - meaning that you invoke object.Dispose().  This is because those classes use limited system resources like file handles and GDI brushes.  If it doesn't implement IDisposable then its usually safe to just let the garbage collector handle it.

Comment: The whole point of `IDisposable` is to free resources that the GC can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

The objects there are all going to get destroyed when the code ends the function, as the variables are out of scope. The `s = Nothing` is redundant because on the next run of the GC, those objects will be destroyed anyway.

Comment: They might not get destroyed when the function returns; the GC is non-deterministic. You don't know when it will run and those objects will be destroyed

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of garbage collection is so that you don't have to manual manage memory anymore. Let the garbage collector do its job.

Additionally, setting a variable to `Nothing` does not mean that the GC is going to kick in and free the memory; the GC is non-deterministic. It could run immediately, it could run in four score and seven years.